# cannot assign <null> to implicit types local variable using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, implicit-typing

I have this

```
var  result = general.GetInformation(int.Parse(ID), F_account, F_Info, Types);
```

this GetInformation is my Entity.Getinformation class.. when I am trying to assign result globly I am getting Cannot Assign to implicit typed local variable?

```
var result = ?
```

what should I assign in global?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "assign result globally", do you mean using it as a class variable?

```
class SomeClass {
    var result = general.GetInformation(int.Parse(ID), F_account, F_Info, Types);
}
```

In that case, [you can't use var](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-var-on-fields) and you would have to use whatever Type GetInformation returns, for example

```
string result =  general.GetInformation(int.Parse(ID), F_account, F_Info, Types);
```

or

```
Entity result =  general.GetInformation(int.Parse(ID), F_account, F_Info, Types);
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're trying to do `var result = null;` which won't work because `null` doesn't tell the compiler what type `result` should be. You would need to use `Sometype result = null;`.

Comment: thanks for that , as you mentioned: this is **wrong** without type : `var studentDetails = null;` but this is **correct** with the type

`List<StudentListVM> studentDetails = null;` , hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Is your error something like "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable"?

Also, is `GetInformation` by any chance a *class*?

If those two are correct, the problem is that you are trying to use implicit typing against a method name, something `var` isn't allowed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

Because your **class** is : **Getinformation**

Then

```
Getinformation result =null;

result = general.GetInformation(int.Parse(ID), F_account, F_Info, Types);
```